# Python/AWS: Update SSM value

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I have a SSM called `/project/db/` with the following content:

```
{
   "HOST":"https://...",
   "VERSION": "1.0"
}
```

Now I want to use Python to update `"VERSION": "2.0"`. What boto3 function should I use? Can you show an complete example please?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64105494/can-i-update-ssm-parameter-value-from-aws-python-lambda

Answer (score 0):

There is no "update" parameter option for SSM.  You'll just use put_parameter to overwrite the value.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.put_parameter